# What does GNOME do with multimedia keys?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, multimedia

GNOME makes multimedia keys, such as fn+directional keys on my laptop, maybe dedicated keys on your keyboard, into very useful keys. They seem to work with a large number of application. What can I do to recreate this using something like xbindkeys?

Comment: Many display managers have their own key bindings, what DM are you using?

Comment: I'm using [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) which is pretty minimal out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Once `xbindkeys` is installed, open up a terminal and type `xbindkeys -k`. This should open a white window (don't bother with it). Just press the button you want to create a rule for on your keyboard.

Below, I pressed the 'Volume Up' button on my keyboard

```
max@max-desktop:/dev> xbindkeys -k
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x10 + c:123
    Mod2 + XF86AudioRaiseVolume
max@max-desktop:/dev>
```

Now take the key definition:

```
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x10 + c:123
    Mod2 + XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

and place it in `~/.xbindkeysrc`. Then change the `("Scheme function")` part to whatever command you want to be run.

For example, this would laumch VLC when I pressed the Volume Up button:

```
"vlc"
    m:0x10 + c:123
    Mod2 + XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

Comment: FYI, `Mod2` probably just means you have numlock on.